# Show new documents in view xe:pagerAddRows without full update

Tags: xpages

When user1 sees view with xe:pagerAddRows which show last document in view, another user2 adds new document. user1 clicks xe:pagerAddRows and can't see new document.

1. How to show new documents for user1 in view using click xe:pagerAddRows without full update page?
2. How to show new documents for user1 created by user2 automatically without click and full update page?

```xml
<xe:dataView
    id="dataView1"
    openDocAsReadonly="true"
    var="viewEntry"
    expandedDetail="true"
    style="margin-top:20.0px"
    repeatControls="true"
    rows="1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel
            xp:key="detail">
            <xp:text
                escape="true"
                style="font-family:Arial;margin-right:10.0px"
                id="computedField1">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertDateTime
                        type="date">
                    </xp:convertDateTime>
                </xp:this.converter>
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    var document : NotesDocument = viewEntry.getDocument();
                    return @Name('[CN]',document.getItemValue('Author'))
                }]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:panel>
        <xe:pagerAddRows
            xp:key="pagerBottomLeft"
            partialExecute="true"
            partialRefresh="true"
            refreshPage="false"
            id="pagerAddRows1"
            for="dataViewUtterance"
            state="true"
            rowCount="1"
            refreshId="ShowMoreUtterance"
            disabledFormat="link">
        </xe:pagerAddRows>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView
            viewName="(Documents)"
            var="viewData"
            ignoreRequestParams="false"
            categoryFilter="#{javascript:
                currentDocument.getDocument().getItemValueString('Flow')}"
            dataCache="id"
            scope="view">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xe:this.data>
</xe:dataView>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.

You can refresh your dataView adding an onclick event to xe:pagerAddRows.

```xml
<xe:pagerAddRows
    xp:key="pagerBottomLeft"
    for="dataView1"
    state="true"
    rowCount="2">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="dataView1">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:pagerAddRows>
```

This causes a refresh of your view and will show documents created by other users since last refresh.

2.

You can refresh your view with the help of a timer function on client side. `setInterval()` will execute a function every x seconds. The following example is executing a partial refresh of dataView1 every 5 seconds. Just add the code to your XPage.

```xml
<xp:scriptBlock
    id="scriptBlockRefresh">
    <xp:this.value>
            <![CDATA[
                setInterval(function() {
                    XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:dataView1}", {})
                }, 5 * 1000)
            ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

3.

It seems to me you'd like to show all view entries in real time and expand view automatically. If that's the case you could change the sort order so that newest documents would appear on top. This way and with the automatic refresh, you would always see the newest entries right on your first page.

Comment: Thanks Knut for the quick reply and correction in my question. The answer is very helpful in solving my problem.